# Can one vectorize the summing of a large data set onto record-specific elements of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a very large data set (order billions of records) that I need to sum on a 2D array.  For each value, there are indices specifying which element of the array the value should be added to:

```
import numpy as np

I = [0, 2, 1, 2, 1]
J = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
X = [2., 5., 0., 6., 4.]

A = np.zeros((3,3), dtype = 'f')

for i in range(len(I)) :
    A[I[i], J[i]] += X[i]
```

with the result

```
> print(A)
[[ 0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 11.]]
```

My question:  Is there a way to vectorize the above operation so as to eliminate the for-loop?

Comment: How much control do you have over the data structures? If your indices must remain as python tuples, you're SOL

Comment: I have complete control over how the data is restructured for processing purpose.  But if I need for-loops to restructure it, I might not gain much.  Raw data set consists of an array of latitudes, array of longitudes, array of values x.  Goal is to add x to a 2-D geospatial array (e.g. 1 degree lat/lon grid elements).

Comment: If you have three arrays, you're golden. That's the easiest arrangement

Comment: I will rewrite the question to express it in terms of three separate arrays.

Comment: That would be the least complicated approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index arrays lend themselves well to fancy indexing. In the simplest case, you can do

```
A[I, J] += X
```

If you have any duplicate indices, i.e., you want to increment some location in `A` more than once, a more robust approach would be

```
np.add.at(A, (I, J), X)
```

Comment: I just reformulated the question - can you write your answer to fit the new description?  Thx.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you mean by "duplicate indices", I do have two cases in the example given: (1,1) and (2,2)

Comment: @GrantPetty. No, I mean attempting to set the same location twice. E.g. `I = [2, 2]; J = [1, 1]`

Comment: I have (1,1) twice and (2,2) twice -- is that what you mean?  Anyway, it seem the np.add.at function is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @GrantPetty. Yes. Same bin with multiple x values. I've added a clarification

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully-vectorized solution:

```
X = [\
     [(0,1), 2. ], \
     [(2,2), 5. ], \
     [(1,1), 0. ], \
     [(2,2), 6. ], \
     [(1,1), 4. ]  \
     ]
# create a dataframe with x, y, and val. I'm not doing it very. 
# efficiently here - but since you control the data structure 
# you can just start from this kind of dataframe. 
records = [(r[0], r[1], t) for r,t in X]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=["x", "y", "val"])

A = np.zeros((3,3), dtype = 'float64')

df = df.groupby(["x", "y"], as_index = False).sum()
A[df.x, df.y] = df.val
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 11.]])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, before your answer showed up, I rewrote my question to accommodate one of the previous comments.

Comment: Also, you're using a comprehension to transform your data. Surely there's a better way.